# How To Update Play Framework Web Application

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

How Do I Provide Update for Play framework web application without killing the server .. 
for example i have made some bug fixes and want to provide update to the users without stopping the server..

version 2.3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some [**HTTP server**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/HTTPServer) as a load-balancer. Just when changes arrives first you need to run second instance of your application on other port/IP/machine, and if it's successfully running stop the first. (One of) the load-balancer's job is to switch between instances depending on it's availability.

Also there's nice guide i.e. by [**nginx**](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/)